# How to push a page with onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I'm newest with firebase, I need verify if the user is login, if is true push it to other page, but nothing happend, please help me!.
I have this function

```
verify(){
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(  function(userTester) {
    if (userTester) {
        this.navCtrl.push(ListPage);
    } else {
        console.log('nobody login');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Did console.log part trigger?

Comment: No, the console dont show anithing, I put a console.log in the true case, and trigger the alert

Comment: So if it is not pushed console.log must have been triggered.

Comment: I had previously placed a console.log in the true and showed the message

Answer (score 0):

I created the function below to help me with that. I created it in the auth.service.ts.

```
isLoggedIn() {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(auth => {
      // Now use value 
      if (auth) {
        // logged in
        console.log('this is their UID: ' + auth.uid);
        console.log('Routing to items');
        this.router.navigate(['/items']);
      } else {
        // logged out
        console.log('User logged out');
      }
    });
  }
```

the console logs above are to verify that I was able to see it. Then I just call it when someone logs in:

```
googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    this.isLoggedIn();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }
```